# CSS pseudo-class: not (: first-child) on the tbody element

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I'm trying to style all tbody tags except the first one but with poor results.

As you can see in the snippet, the style is applied to all elements, including the first one, where am I wrong?

```css
div.cont_table_toggle table#general_list tbody.divider:not(:first-child) {
  border-top: 8px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="cont_table_toggle">
  <table id="general_list" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>AAAA</th>
        <th>BBBB</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="block-1" class="divider">
      <tr>
        <td>1111</td><td>2222</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="block-2" class="divider">
      <tr>
        <td>3333</td><td>4444</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="block-3" class="divider">
      <tr>
        <td>5555</td><td>6666</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `tbody.divider:not(:first-of-type)`.

> The `:first-of-type` selector matches every element that is the first child, of a particular type, of its parent.

Reference : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_first-of-type.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Try it below.

```css
div.cont_table_toggle table#general_list tbody.divider:not(:first-of-type) {
  border-top: 8px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="cont_table_toggle">
  <table id="general_list" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>AAAA</th>
        <th>BBBB</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="block-1" class="divider">
      <tr>
        <td>1111</td><td>2222</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="block-2" class="divider">
      <tr>
        <td>3333</td><td>4444</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="block-3" class="divider">
      <tr>
        <td>5555</td><td>6666</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Both answers are helpful but I find this one more suited to my needs, thanks

Answer (score 1):

*`tbody`* is not the first child of the `table`. So the `:first-child` selector does not work.  If you remove the `thead`, it works.

```css
div.cont_table_toggle table#general_list tbody.divider:not(:first-child) {
  border-top: 8px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="cont_table_toggle">
  <table id="general_list" class="table table-bordered">

    <tbody id="block-1" class="divider">
      <tr>
        <td>1111</td><td>2222</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="block-2" class="divider">
      <tr>
        <td>3333</td><td>4444</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="block-3" class="divider">
      <tr>
        <td>5555</td><td>6666</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

You could  use `:not(#block-1)`, `:nth-child(2)`, or as the other answer has suggested, `:not(:first-of-type)`.

---

## Use `not(#block-1)`

The first `tbody` has `id` that you can use. As you many know, id must unique.

`tbody:not(#block-1)` selects all **tbodys** except the first one.

```css
#general_list tbody:not(#block-1) {
  border-top: 8px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="cont_table_toggle">
  <table id="general_list" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>AAAA</th>
        <th>BBBB</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="block-1" class="divider">
      <tr>
        <td>1111</td><td>2222</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="block-2" class="divider">
      <tr>
        <td>3333</td><td>4444</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="block-3" class="divider">
      <tr>
        <td>5555</td><td>6666</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

## Use `:not(:nth-child(2))`

```css
#general_list tbody:not(:nth-child(2)) {
  border-top: 8px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="cont_table_toggle">
  <table id="general_list" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>AAAA</th>
        <th>BBBB</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="block-1" class="divider">
      <tr>
        <td>1111</td><td>2222</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="block-2" class="divider">
      <tr>
        <td>3333</td><td>4444</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="block-3" class="divider">
      <tr>
        <td>5555</td><td>6666</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```